# Error using Selenium Chrome Webdriver with C#

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

```
            options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
            
            
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("");
            string currentDay = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek.ToString();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            switch(currentDay)
            {
```

Had a problem, where it doesn't hide the browser, what can I do?

Comment: You could downgrade to chrome version 83.

Comment: Does google allow that? If so, then how?

Comment: It definitely allows you to do so.

Comment: go over here https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php uninstall chrome

Comment: This may be useful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66075973/1068246

Answer (score 1):

Your chrome web-driver version need to match with your google chrome version which is install on your PC.

please use below link to download chromedriver.

[chromedriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

Answer (score 0):

First, check your Chrome version with following instructions:

1. Click the three dots in the upper-right corner of the window.
2. Hover your cursor over "Help."
3. Click "About Google Chrome."
   The version of your Google Chrome browser will appear on the next window, toward the top of the screen.

Then download the matched chrome webdriver version.
Via this link:
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads