# C# Selenium Webdriver Exception | This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 85

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[MyChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=88.0.4324.96/)

My Google Chrome version: **88.0.4324.150**

I found some [solutions](https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/setting-up-selenium-in-visual-studio/) but the don't worked for me.
I want to open Google Chrome throw the Selenium, but it don't work yet.

**Error**

```sh
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 85 (SessionNotCreated)
  Source=WebDriver
  StackTrace:
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeOptions options)
   at RSelenium.start_Browser() in C:\Users\ruper\source\repos\T\T\RSelenium.cs:line 30
   at T.Form1.btn_selenium_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\ruper\source\repos\T\T\Form1.cs:line 61
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at T.Program.Main() in C:\Users\ruper\source\repos\T\T\Program.cs:line 47
```

**Code**

```
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("webdriver.chrome.driver", @"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("start-maximized");
options.AddArguments("disable-infobars");
options.AddArguments("--disable-extensions");
options.AddArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.AddArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
options.AddArguments("--no-sandbox");
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: @PDHide sadly I already dried to Chance the Versions, but this won't solve the Problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads?tmpl=%2Fsystem%2Fapp%2Ftemplates%2Fprint%2F&showPrintDialog=1

Download chrome driver 88 from here

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Chrome_ChromeDriver.htm

you can see the constructor accepts the path of executable

so use

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("c:/DownloadeddirectoryPath",options);
```

**Note:** the path should be PATH to directory containing chromedriver.exe and not the chromedriver.exe itself

Comment: Thank you! Worked now. My issue was that I only need to point to the Path, not the .exe

Comment: Glad it helped , reading the class documentation is the best way to know what would be the expected solution

Comment: I was confused and thought I had to download version 85 because of the message, but I needed to download the version which my browser uses.

Comment: You have to run the chromedrive.exe too for it to work.

Comment: @NareshBisht is right. In my case I had to write the whole path including "chromedrive.exe".

Answer (score 1):

Another way of ensuring that webdriver and Chrome (actually I am suggesting Chromium) versions are the same is to download both from the same Chromium snapshots page.
https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html

For Example, v96 Chromium Linux and the respective web driver is here:
https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Linux_x64/929513/

The build numbers for stable versions could be found here: https://github.com/Bugazelle/chromium-all-old-stable-versions

PDHide already described how to point to the webdriver path. To point to Chromium binary/executable, use

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.BinaryLocation = "/full/location/including/binary";
var driver = new ChromeDriver("/folder/where/webdriver/located", options);
```

Answer (score 1):

@PDHide's solution had solved my issue, but again I have faced the same problem.
And I have solved it like that now:

I have added WebDriverManager from Nuget into my project.
I have added this line to onload:

```
new DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig(), VersionResolveStrategy.MatchingBrowser);
```

And I have made a method that returns the WebDriver object:

```
 public IWebDriver GetChromeDriver()
 {
     ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
     options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
     string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/Chrome", "ChromeDriver.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
     List<KeyValuePair<string, DateTime>> lstFile = new List<KeyValuePair<string, DateTime>>();
     foreach (string file in files)
     {
         lstFile.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, DateTime>(file, File.GetLastWriteTime(file)));
     }
     string filePath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(lstFile.OrderByDescending(r => r.Value).First().Key);
     return new ChromeDriver(filePath, options);
 }
```

And I am calling it like that:

```
IWebDriver myDriverChrome = new BasicOperations().GetChromeDriver();
```