# C# Selenium Webdriver chromedriver problem with version

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a problem with chrome and chromedriver version, I tried to find some solution but without success.

`System.InvalidOperationException : session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 106 Current browser version is 108.0.5359.125 with binary path`

I updated version of chromedriver through NuGet, but It's still the same...

[Google Chrome version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIbYh.png)
[chromedriver version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PShhY.png)

Do you have any idea what's wrong?

I tried to update version of chrome driver through NuGet and manually. Also uninstalling it and installing again but it didn't worked.

Comment: Do you possibly have another version of chromedriver hidden away somewhere? The error says it is version 106, but the chromedriver in your screenshot is 108, so it looks like it is not using the version that you installed with Nuget

Comment: In this situation I'd try closing Visual Studio (or whichever IDE you're using) and deleting the project's `bin` and `obj` folders (and those of any projects referenced by your project) to ensure you get a clean build without the old ChromeDriver version being cached anywhere.

Comment: Yeah, Thank you very much, indeed I had 2 test projects in solution, and i forgot about one of them, where i'd chromedriver too. I was using only of them for most of the time, and there were several chrome updates, but for some reason it failed just now... Thanks, and sorry for bothering for my oversight.

Comment: This may be useful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66075973/1068246